# Multiple form binding with the same reactive form control using *ngFor validation issue

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, web

I am trying to make a blogsite comment system. Where a blog post has a comment form field and each comment has a reply form field. But the reply form and the comment form have the same input fields so I am trying to initialize the comment form and reply form with same reactive form. Look like these:

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.commentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        comment: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
 }
```

My Html code looks like these:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of allBlogPost">
<p>item.blogPostText</p>
<div class='comment'>
    <div *ngFor="let comment of allBlogPost.comments">
        <p>{{comment.comment_text}}</p>
        <div *ngFor="let reply of comment.replies">
            <p>{{reply.reply_text}}</p>
        </div>
        <form [formGroup]="commentForm" (ngSubmit)="onReplySubmit()">
            <input type="text" formControlName="comment"/>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="commentForm.invalid">Reply</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <form [formGroup]="commentForm" (ngSubmit)="onCommentSubmit()">
        <input type="text" formControlName="comment"/>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="commentForm.invalid">Comment</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The code is working fine whenever I am posting comments and replies. But the problem is when I write comment inside comment form or reply form the submit button is activated as the form is now valid. But all the other form submit button also became activated (as my assumption it is happening for one of the form being validate) though they remain untouched. But now I don't know how to solve the problem.

I need to activate the particular submit button when a particular form is valid. How can I get the funtionality in angular way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few approaches. One way is to make a comment component for your app. This will ensure that you have more instances of `formGroup`

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of allBlogPost">
<p>item.blogPostText</p>

<div class='comment'>
  <app-comment *ngFor="let comment of allBlogPost.comments" [comment]="comment">
  </app-comment>
</div>
```

Use the `@Input` decorator in your new Comment Component like this

**comment.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comment',
  templateUrl: './comment.component.html'
})
export class CommentComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() comment;

ngOnInit(){
  this.commentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    comment: ['', [Validators.required]]
  });
}

// Remember to move the rest of the comment logic from your bloglist...

}
```

**comment.component.html**

```html
<p>{{comment.comment_text}}</p>
<div *ngFor="let reply of comment.replies">
  <p>{{reply.reply_text}}</p>
</div>
<form [formGroup]="commentForm" (ngSubmit)="onReplySubmit()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="comment"/>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="commentForm.invalid">Reply</button>
</form>
</div>
<form [formGroup]="commentForm" (ngSubmit)="onCommentSubmit()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="comment"/>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="commentForm.invalid">Comment</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have tried other approaches as I don't want to move the business logic from that component but all approaches made me failed. But this approach is worked for me. Thanks after all.